# KDB - Why does upsert work when insert does not

Tags: kdb

I am trying to manipulate the upd function in a KDB tickerplant so that it can accept a table as the data argument.

When trying to insert locally, insert does not seem to like being passed the data from the table but will handle a list of lists fine when passed from the feedhandler. Why is this?

```
tbl1:([] sym:`symbol$(); price:`int$(); vol:`long$())
tbl2:([] sym:3?`3;price:3?10i;vol:3?100j)
insert[tbl1;(value each tbl2)]
'type
upd:{[t;x] upsert[t;x]}
upd[`tbl1;(value each tbl2)]
`tbl1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your example above

1. `insert` requires the left argument to be a symbol atom
2. the right argument needs align with the columns of the table

```
q)insert[`tbl1;value flip tbl2];tbl1
sym price vol
-------------
lhk 8     49
mga 1     82
mio 7     40
```

`upsert` is more flexible